# Assign the Recipes to LifeCycle Events in Opsworks by Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

In the opsworks console, in the layer page, we can configure the Custom Chef Recipes for the lifecycle events of the stack. ([Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/using-s3-events.html)).

I am creating a cloudformation template that creates all the opsworks stack, layers, instances and apps and I need to specify these receipes too in the template. Is that possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible simply by using the [`CustomRecipes`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-layer.html#cfn-opsworks-layer-customrecipes) property in the [`AWS::OpsWorks::Layer`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-layer.html) resource:

```
"CustomRecipes" : {
           "Setup"     : ["cookbook1::setup","cookbook2::setup"],
           "Configure" : ["settings::default"],
           "Deploy": ["application12::deploy"]
        },
```